# Why is my FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-acs

I have in previously used this in my ACS Federated secured applications:

```
        FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated +=
FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated;
```

in the global.asax.cs file. For some reason its null in my current application and i cant figure out why. Anyone got some hints about what might cause this.

```
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="site" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add name="https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net/" thumbprint="thmp" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />      
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false" issuer="https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="site" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: Do you have the federation module in your configuration?

Comment: yes. i will attach it to the question.

Comment: It looks like its null until the first time its used.